# How to safely quit vim if there's some unsaved changes?

Tags: quit

If I have changed a bunch of files but without saving and maybe I have another pile of noname buffers which are changed and without a file name.

I want vim to prompt confirmation for each one of the above files. if it's a changed file without saving then ask me whether to save it. if it's a noname buffer asking me whether to save it, if yes then provide a file name.

It's just like in some other modeless editor, when you edit a lot of files and click the close button to close the editor, it'll prompt confirmations.

Comment: Well, technically, if you just do `:q`, Vim does warn about unsaved buffers.

Comment: Well, what have you done to gVim, that it doesn't do it for you? It always asks me about unsaved buffers when pressing the 'X'

Comment: The command `set confirm` might be close to what you're asking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The option [`confirm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27confirm%27) does what you describe for modified files.

With

```
set confirm
```

in my vimrc, it gives the following prompt when I `:quit` a modified NoName buffer:

```
Save changes to "Untitled"?
[Y]es, (N)o, Save (A)ll, (D)iscard All, (C)ancel:
```

For me, if it's an unnamed buffer and you answer `(Y)es` to the prompt, it opens it. You could then `:write filename`, and `:qall` again (seems like any buffers you've already said `(N)o` to the prompt are cleared).

Comment: there's a problem, when I have multiple noname buffer, I can't figure out which noname buffer it's asking me to confirm, it always prompt the same message: `save changes to "untitled"? [Y]es, [N]o ...`

Comment: So you would like a preview of the file you are being asked about? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As an idea, you could write a script to give the behaviour you're after. Maybe something that starts off by closing all non-modified buffers, perhaps something with `if (&modified == 0)`...